# Программа зациклилась , но я не понимаю как . java

Tags: java

Решаю задачу , нужно найти суммy от L до r  q раз , программа работает правильно , но не заканчивается , пожалуйста помогите найти проблему.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n+1];
        int[] part = new int[n + 1];
        part[0] = 0;
        for (int i =1 ; i <= n;i++) {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
            part[i] = part[i -1] + array[i];

        }

        for(int qq = 1 ; qq <= q;q++) {
            int  l = scan.nextInt();
            int  r = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(part[r] - part[l -1]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `for(int qq = 1 ; qq <= q;q++) {` -> `for(int qq = 1 ; qq <= q;qq++) {`

Comment: Спасибо , но теперь мне стыдно за такую ошибку

Comment: всякое бывает))

Comment: давайте переменным более осмысленные названия и такие ошибки будут для вас очень редкими и легко находимыми.